# Wordpress как записать номер поста в атрибут через цикл

Tags: wordpress

как можно записать в data-elem номер или id поста? у меня каждый data-elem Должен быть уникальный своё число чтобы например первом елементе было data-elem="1" а во втором data-elem="2" и тд... пробовал такой такой вариант но не работает, `data-elem="<?php $count = $custom_posts->post_count; ?>"`

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=86' ); ?>
                <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="faq__item" data-elem="">
                        <div class="faq__header"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                        <div class="faq__body"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                else : ?>
                    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решается всё простейшим инкрементом

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=86' ); ?>
<?php $post_num = 0; ?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $post_num++; ?>
    <div class="faq__item" data-elem="<?= $post_num; ?>">
        <div class="faq__header"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <div class="faq__body"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else : ?>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Для вывода же ID записи воспользуйтесь `$post->ID` или `the_ID()`

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю к ответу Pyramidhead:

Если нужно при этом передать значение переменной $post_num во вложенный шаблон, нужно перед его вызовом прописать **set_query_var**:

```
set_query_var( 'post_num', $post_num );
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );
```